# Limit Group Concat for first 5 products

Tags: mysql, sql, limit, concatenation, group-concat

I have a few group concats in my query, but the loading time is very slow, because I think de query concats everything and limit only the end result. My Prijs-table is very big so it takes about 8 seconds now to load.

This is my query:

```
SELECT babyfoontest.idnummer, babyfoontest.typenummer, deeplink, merk,  afbeelding, GROUP_CONCAT(price) as `prijs`, GROUP_CONCAT(producturl) as `deeplink`, $query_string_variable AS total
FROM prijzen
INNER JOIN babyfoontest
ON  prijzen.eancode = babyfoontest.ean
WHERE 
(shopnaam = 'amazon' AND categorie = 'Babby en dreumes')
GROUP BY eancode
ORDER BY total DESC, ABS(prijs) 
LIMIT 0, 5;
```

I only want to show the first 5 products but how can I limit the group-concats to the first 5 rows? Do I need a Subquery? If so, how do I do it in this example? Sorry, am not an expert in SQL.

Thanks so much!

Kind regards,
Mark

Comment: if you provide data sample and expected result that would help a lot

Comment: Hi Alex, I want to show 5 products on my result page with a price comparison (from lowest price to the highest). All webshops with prices are in my prijzen-table so I want to match on EAN (unique number) and show all prices, shopnames and webshop links matched to the EAN. With group-concate I show all prices but it takes a long time. Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: to many words. just provide sample of data table and expected result

Comment: What system are you using? The SELECT clause is usually applied at the end of query processing. Thus, the concatenation should only happen for the first 5 products. Have you tested the query without the CONCAT in the SELECT clause? Is it faster then?